# Castle - Registering unknown implementation

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle

I'm fairly new to IoC and Castle and I'm having hard time registering a class by implemented interface.

In my application there are several assemblies each with a class implementing interface **IErrorCodes**. At runtime it is determined if one (at most) of these assemblies/classes is present AND also there is always **DefaultErrorCodes** class which should be used when no real implementation exists.

Following code results in implementation (eg. **UkErrorCodes**) being present in the *Services* part of container, but Castle gives me error when app gets to the part where the implementation of **IErrorCodes** should be injected saying "did you forget to proxy it"

```
container.Register(
    Classes.FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("bin")).
                BasedOn<IErrorCodes>().
                Unless(t=> t.IsAbstract).
                WithServiceBase(),
    Component.For<IErrorCodes>()
               .IsFallback(c => c == typeof(DefaultErrorCodes)).LifestyleSingleton());
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me:

```
        container.Register(
            Component.
                For<IErrorCodes>().
                ImplementedBy<DefaultErrorCodes>().
                IsFallback(),
            Classes.
                FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("bin")).
                BasedOn<IErrorCodes>().
                Unless(t => t.IsAbstract).
                WithServiceBase().
                LifestyleSingleton());
```